# Selenium - how to get runtime generated iframe id

Tags: java, firefox, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a webpage as a blackbox (hard requirement)

the page has a button, on click it calls a function that generates an iframe with a dynamic id, i.e clicking on the same button will create the same frame content but every time with different

```
<input type="button" value="some txt" onclick="return displayIframe(if_42222440278);">
```

this creates an iframe  like this

```
<iframe id="6356469882593" class="someClass" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="/Pages/somePage.aspx', '', 'width=740px,height=629&rand=6356469882593" allowtransparency="true">
```

how can I get the iframe id??

these are my tries so far:

attempt 1: resulted in array of 10 objects all null

```
List<WebElement> iframes = webDriver.findElements(By.id("iframe"));
```

attempt 2: resulted in exception that the element doesn't exist

```
webDriver.switchTo().frame(0)
WebElement editable = webDriver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

any other suggestions?

Comment: Html would help understand your problem.

Comment: @Husam i've added the html

Answer (score 1):

Please try below.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagname("iframe"))
driver.switchTo().frame(elements.get(0));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
List<WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='someClass']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(we.get(0)); //Switch to iframe.
WebElement activeElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
/*Do anything here.
 activeElement.findElement(b).click();*/
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); //Switch to original frame.
```

You can identify iframe, switch to it, work in it and switch back to your default content.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
iframeID = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='somePage.aspx']")).getAttribute("id");
```